# Inserting an XML Element w/ Python

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-2.7

I have a quick and dirty build script that needs to update a couple of lines in a small xml config file. Since the file is so small, I'm using an admittedly inefficient process to update the file in place just to keep things simple:

```
def hide_osx_dock_icon(app):
    for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(app, 'Contents', 'Info.plist'), inplace=True):
        line = re.sub(r'(<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>)', '<key>LSUIElement</key><string>1</string>\g<1>', line.strip(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    print line.strip()
```

The idea is to find the `<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>` text and insert the `LSUIElement` content right in front of it. I'm doing something just like this in another area and it's working fine so I guess I'm just missing something, but I don't see it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are printing the last line only, because the `print` line is not indented far enough. Is that a posting mistake?

Comment: Argh, no. No it's not a mistake. Well, not in the post anyway. That's the part I just couldn't see. If you'll put this in as an answer, I'll mark it as _the_ answer. Thanks for the extra set of eyeballs.

Comment: Done; been there, done that, the rubber duck knows all secrets and tells noone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing only the *last* line, because your `print` statement falls outside of the for loop:

```
for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(app, 'Contents', 'Info.plist'), inplace=True):
    line = re.sub(r'(<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>)', '<key>LSUIElement</key><string>1</string>\g<1>', line.strip(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print line.strip()
```

Indent that line to match the previous:

```
for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(app, 'Contents', 'Info.plist'), inplace=True):
    line = re.sub(r'(<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>)', '<key>LSUIElement</key><string>1</string>\g<1>', line.strip(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    print line.strip()
```